# Angular 2 keep route alive even when not navigated to it

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 2 is there a way to keep a navigation route alive even when it isn't navigated to? My purpose for this is I'm attempting to put a webgl canvas into a angular 2 route. Now by default whenever a route is navigated to it initializes the component and loads all of the needed resources then when navigating away it destroys the component and removes the view from the Dom. This causes 2 problems when using webgl the main one being there are only a specific amount of instances of webgl allowed otherwise it could overload the graphics card. So if the route is navigated to and away from multiple times there's a chance that limit can be reached because it's creating a new webgl instance every time the route is navigated to. Also webgl often time requires complex variables and resources and it would be nice to be able to keep those variables alive so they don't have to be loaded again and in some cases even use them outside of the route.

So my proposed solution is to keep the component alive but hidden so that resources and variables are kept alive is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you could try to use the `CanReuse` interface and its `routerCanReuse`. If the component implements this method and it returns true, the component won't be destroyed and the same component instance will be reused across routes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `
    (...)
  `
})
class MyCmp implements CanReuse, OnReuse {
  routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I'm curious though is there another one to tell it to create the component before its navigated to. During the app initialization